# Issue Trying to start the application in IBM websphere server when i am connected to the VPN network

Tags: websphere, atg

Issue Trying to start the IBM websphere server when i am connected to the VPN network.

I cannot start my application in WebSphere Application server when connected over the VPN( I have all required host entries). Logs suggest that the ATG repositories failed to start over the VPN Network ( some problem with the connection timeout in datasources in the application)
I am able to connect to the Datasources without any issues using other tools like Sql Developer etc.

Can someone please explain why this is happening only over the VPN network but not when i am connected to the local Intranet network.

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. What WAS version are you using? What do you mean that you cannot start application? (application should be already running if server is started, are you having problems starting the server) What logs? Please attach log fragment with error message. SQL developer cannot connect to the data sources defined in WebSphere, more likely you meant that you can connect to database itself (so try to be clear).

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. I am new to this. Anyways,
I am using WAS v7.0. I have problem running my application as it accesses remote datasources.
By connecting to the datasources i meant, i can connect to the database.
Please find the log fragment in the comment below.
I am suspecting a network configuration issue here as i get this error only when i am connected over a VPN (instead of the local intranet). Please let me know if you require any other information.

Comment: 00000016 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0006W: Transaction 000001472F9123140000000A00000009DBA267FB14204157CE0CEA12BD8203E1462768C3000001472F9123140000000A00000009DBA267FB14204157CE0CEA12BD8203E1462768C300000001 has timed out after 120 seconds.

00000016 TimeoutManage I   WTRN0124I: When the timeout occurred the thread with which the transaction is, or was most recently, associated was Thread[Thread-36,5,main]. The stack trace of this thread when the timeout occurred was: 
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Comment: Are you restarting WAS, while you are connected via VPN? Are you using same userid? I don't see connection between accessing WAS via VPN or not and how it could affect connection to remote database.

Comment: Yes. I am restarting WAS(more like killing the instance then starting again) while connected via VPN. I am using the same userid. Even i don't understand why i am not able to start the WAS Application over VPN. That was the question in the first place.

Comment: Warning message suggests that your application timeouts on reading from socket. Please provide full stack trace, so we can see what is the origin of that call.